# How to use Javascript .submit(function(event) { for multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Ok, so I have the following Javascript:

```
//Form handling
var form = $('#form-ajax');
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
$(form).submit(function(event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {
        //Do something
    }).fail(function(data) {
        //Do something
    });
});
```

Which essentially overrides the default form submission and handles things using Ajax instead.

To use it, I just need to add the `form-ajax` id to the form, and add an empty div with the id `form-messages`; and any response from the form will be displayed in this div without the page reloading.

My issue is that I want to use this same Javascript call for multiple forms, and I can't quite work out how.

I figured that changing form-ajax to a class would do the trick. So

```
var form = $('.form-ajax');
```

rather than:

```
var form = $('#form-ajax');
```

But it didn't help. In both cases, if multiple forms are used with this:

```
<div id="form-messages"></div>

<form class="form-ajax" method="post" action="dosomething.php">
</form>
<form class="form-ajax" method="post" action="dosomethingelse.php">
</form>
```

Submitting either form would trigger the second to be posted. I assume due to the order they're loaded in the DOM.

Any ideas how to solve this so that I can re-use this one handler/event.

Comment: Use `this` instead of `form` inside the event handler. Learn more about jQuery event handling basics: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var form = $('.form-ajax');
```

You are setting `form` to potentially a *collection* of elements, not just one.  This might not be a big deal here:

```
$(form).submit(function(event) {
    // event handler
});
```

Because jQuery will simply add that handler to the `submit` event of each form in the collection.  But it very much becomes a big deal here:

```
var formData = $(form).serialize();
```

Because you're serializing *the whole collection* of form elements, not just one.  Within the scope of the event handler, you can use `this` to reference the specific element being handled at runtime:

```
var formData = $(this).serialize();
```

That way you only serialize what's in the scope of that one form, instead of all the forms.

The same issue applies here:

```
$(form).attr('action')
```

Which should also be scoped to just the form which invoked the handler:

```
$(this).attr('action')
```

Comment: This is the best answer here

Answer (score 1):

To solve that problem you should create a variable inside the submit function that has a reference to the current form. Check your code bellow with the modifications:

```
//Form handling
var form = $('.anyClass');
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
$(form).submit(function(event) {
    // Current form
    var currentForm = $(this);
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = currentForm.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: currentForm.attr('action'),
        data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {
        //Do something
    }).fail(function(data) {
        //Do something
    });
});
```

Hope it helps. Good luck.